# Challenging: The inverse function of $y=\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, inverse

I am trying to find out the inverse function of $y=\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{1-x}$.

Here's a picture of I've got so far:
$$x=(1/8)^{1-y}$$
$$e^x=e^{(1-y)\ln1/8}=(1-y)\ln\frac18$$
$$\ln8e^x=1-y$$
$$y=1-\ln8e^x$$

Comment: The inverse of a function depends on which range and domain you consider; please state these in order to determine the inverse function

Comment: In your solution .jpg, there are serious mistakes.

Comment: What are they ? That would really help me

Comment: @AdamCora that is in the second step. it should've been $e^{\ln x}=e^{(1-y)\ln \frac{1}{8}}$

Answer (score 3):

Switching variables and taking the logarithm base $\frac{1}{8}$ of both sides: $$1-y=\log_{\frac{1}{8}}(x)$$ Then solving for $y$: $$y=1-\log_{\frac{1}{8}}(x)$$ Logarithms are the inverse of exponentials. So for example: $$a=b^x \implies \log_ba=x$$

Answer (score 3):

Third line in your .jpg file is mistake. It must be:
$$x=e^{\ln\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)(1-y)}$$
Then take "$\ln$" of both sides to get
$$\ln x = \ln\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)(1-y).$$
Then, since $\ln(\frac{1}{8})=-\ln8$, we have
$$\ln x = \ln8(y-1)$$
or
$$\frac{\ln x}{\ln 8}=y-1.$$
Hence,
$$y=\frac{1}{\ln 8}\ln x+1$$ is the solution. You may write it in base 8 logarithm  as $y=\log_8 x +1$.

Comment: Shouldn't the 8 be at the top since we're dividing by 8 and not multiplying by 8 ?

Comment: There is no 8. You mean $\ln 8$?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant

Comment: $\frac{\ln x}{\ln a} = \log_{a} x$ @AdamCora

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, when dealing with variables in the exponentials that you want to get down, use the log function.
$$
log_{1/8}y =1-x => x= 1- log_{1/8}y
$$